# How to compile library on C using GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, include, libraries

I made a library with the files `pila.h` and `pila.c`. I compile the file `pila.c` with `gcc pila.c -c` and this library works fine. I have tested it.

Then I made another library. This library has the files `pila_funciones_extra.h` and `pila_funciones_extra.c`. In this library I need to include the first library. In the file `pila_funciones_extra.h` I put the next line to include it:

```
#include "pila.h"
```

and in the file `pila_funciones_extra.c` I put the next line:

```
#include "pila_funciones_extra.h"
```

as it has to be.

But when I try to compile the file `pila_funciones_extra.c` the compiler doensn't recognize the inclusion of the library `pila`. It says that the functions, structures, constants and macros that are defined in the library `pila` haven't been defined.

I tried to compile it with `gcc pila_funciones_extra.c -c` and `gcc pila_funciones_extra.c -c pila.o` but it doesn't work.

I made sure that all the files are in the same folder.

I'm working on Ubuntu.

Can anyone tell me the right way to compile it?

Comment: Please post the _exact_ compiler error you're getting (compile line + the first 5-10 lines of output).

Comment: Have you use the flag `-l pila.o` when you are compiling `pila_funciones_extra.c`?

Comment: Are you using any inclusion-guards? `#ifndef's`? Eg if you use the same in both headers then only the `_extra.h` will get inc'ed.

Comment: In short, take time to learn about `make`

Answer (score 32):

First, always take the habit to compile with `-Wall` (and perhaps even *also* `-Wextra` to get even more warnings) option to `gcc`; it gives you almost all warnings, and you should improve your code till no warnings are given.

Then you often want to be able to debug your code, so also pass `-g` to `gcc`. Once you are confident with your code you could ask `gcc` to produce optimized machine code with `-O2`. Learn to use the `gdb` debugger.

So compile your first library, assuming its source files `first1.c` and `first2.c` are in `FirstLib/` directory, with e.g.

```
cd FirstLib/
gcc -Wall -g -c first1.c -o first1.o
gcc -Wall -g -c first2.c -o first2.o
```

At this point, you should use a `Makefile` and learn how to use `make`, in particular because you want to get your `libfirst.a` with

```
ar ruv libfirst.a first1.o first2.o
ranlib libfirst.a
```

Then you can pass `-L../FirstLib -lfirst` as the last options to the `gcc` command compiling and linking your program using your `libfirst.a`

Then compile your second library by having your `Makefile` in directory `SecondLib/` which very probably should contain

```
# in SecondLib/Makefile
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -I../FirstLib/ -Wall -g
## add your other stuff for make
```

etc etc. You really want to learn how to use `make` and write your own `Makefile`-s so take time to read the [GNU make documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/).

You may want to pass `-H` to `gcc` to have it tell you all the included files, and you may want to also use [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) (in addition & replacement of  `make`) to debug your more complex `Makefile`-s (notably by running `remake -x`). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16751650/841108) is an example of `Makefile`; you'll find many others!

Read also the [Program Library Howto](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/).

Answer (score 4):

For a library composed of many files you can first compile then separately and then do this:

```
ar ruv mylib.a pila_funciones_extra.o pila.o
ranlib mylib.a
```

This command causes the library to be created if it does not already exist. If it does, the .o files are updated (or added to this library). The *ranlib* is used to randomize the library in a way that is useful for the loader.

When you use this library, you do:

```
gcc -o myapp myapp.c mylib.a
```