# A Makefile with Multiple Executables

Tags: c, makefile

I am trying to write a makefile which uses macros to create multiple executables from multiple files at once. I tried searching through previously answered questions but, because I am fairly new to programming in C as well as working with gcc, I was not able to find an answer to my question.

Here is what I have so far:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-I.
OBJ = ex1.c ex3.c
EXECUTABLE = ex1 ex3

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJ)
    gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -f $(EXECUTABLE)
```

I would like the line

```
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJ)
```

to create executables ex1 and ex3 from files ex1.c ex3.c respectively.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For this particular case, where each executable has a single source file with `.c` extension, all you need is a one line Makefile:

```
all: ex1 ex3
```

The built-in default rules for `make` then work already:

```
$ make
cc -O2 -pipe   ex1.c  -o ex1
cc -O2 -pipe   ex3.c  -o ex3
```

Behind the scene, `make` is using the [POSIXly mandated built-in single suffix rule](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html)

```
.c:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

Vary the command to your liking with `make CC=gcc CFLAGS=-O2 LDFLAGS=-s` and similar.

Trivia of the day: in fact, if you are willing to name the targets when invoking `make`, **you can use an empty or even *run without* any Makefile:**

```
$ make -f /dev/null CC=gcc CFLAGS=-O2 LDFLAGS=-s ex1 ex3
gcc -O2 -s ex1.c  -o ex1
gcc -O2 -s ex3.c  -o ex3
$ rm -f Makefile ex1 ex3
$ make CC=gcc CFLAGS=-O2 LDFLAGS=-s ex1 ex3
gcc -O2 -s ex1.c  -o ex1
gcc -O2 -s ex3.c  -o ex3
```

**Make magic!**

As a rule of thumb, don't reinvent the wheel (or rules), use the rules that are already there. It simplifies your and make's life a lot. This makes for small and sexy makefiles to impress the ladies with :-)

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks for some insight into the inner workings of the make command.

Answer (score 3):

Some suggestions (assuming you use *GNU* [make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/), not something else)

First, run once `make -p`, you'll understand what builtin rules `make` is knowing. Look in particular for `COMPILE.c` and `LINK.c`

Then, I suggest

```
 CFLAGS= -g -Wall -I.
```

<sup>(because you really want `-g` for debugging, and `-Wall` to get most warnings)</sup>

And you probably don't need

```
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJ)
    gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)
```

However, I suggest adding before most other rules

```
.PHONY: all clean

all: $(EXECUTABLES)
```

Actually, I would code your `Makefile` (for *GNU* `make`!) as follow

```
# file Makefile
CC= gcc
RM= rm -vf
CFLAGS= -Wall -g
CPPFLAGS= -I.
SRCFILES= ex1.c ex2.c ## or perhaps $(wildcard *.c)
OBJFILES= $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SRCFILES))
PROGFILES= $(patsubst %.c, %, $(SRCFILES))

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(PROGFILES)
clean:
     $(RM) $(OBJFILES) $(PROGFILES) *~
## eof Makefile
```

Remember that <kbd>tab</kbd> is a significant character in `Makefile`-s (action part of [rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rules.html)). In this answer, lines starting with four spaces at least should really start with a <kbd>tab</kbd> character.

Once everything is debugged consider running `make clean` to clean everything, and then `make -j CFLAGS=-O2 all` to compile in parallel everything with optimizations.

At last, I recommend using [`remake`](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) and running `remake -x` to debug complex `Makefile`-s

Of course, I'm supposing that your directory has only single-file programs.

BTW, there are other [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tools. Perhaps you might consider using [omake](http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/omake.html) or [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/). For building large programs (millions of source code lines) consider also [automake](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/), [ccache](https://ccache.dev/), [cmake](https://cmake.org/), [icecream](http://linuxintro.org/wiki/Icecream). In some cases, consider generating some C code with [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp), [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/), [SWIG](https://swig.org/), etc... or using your own [Python](https://python.org/) or [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/guile.html) script (or C meta-program). See also [this draft](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) report.

<sup>Don't forget to use a version control system like [git](http://git-scm.com/) for your source files. It is also time to learn such a tool.</sup>

Comment: `COMPILE.c` and `LINK.c` are GNUisms; you make an assupmtion here that the OP is using GNU make. The better (portable) idea is to use the built-in single suffix rule for `.c`.

Comment: Yes, I added a mention of GNU make

Comment: Thank you for the advice as well as suggesting git and omake.

Answer (score 1):

The following answer includes multiple executable such as initiate, process1, process2, ..., process4.

```
LOCAL_INCLUDE=./

all: clean process_first process_second init

process_first:
    gcc -g -o process1  -I$(LOCAL_INCLUDE) process1.c  -lzmq  -L. -L./.
    gcc -g -o process2  -I$(LOCAL_INCLUDE) process2.c  -lzmq  -L. -L./.

process_second:
    gcc -g -o process3  -I$(LOCAL_INCLUDE) process3.c  -lzmq  -L. -L./.
    gcc -g -o process4  -I$(LOCAL_INCLUDE) process4.c  -lzmq  -L. -L./.

init:
    gcc -g -o initiate -I$(LOCAL_INCLUDE) initiate.c -lzmq -lconfig -lpthread -L. -L./. -ldl -lrt

clean:
    rm -rf init_manager.o init_manager
    rm -rf process1 process2 process3 process4
```

NOTE: It is a good practice to clean and touch all the executable files before making them again.

Answer (score 0):

You're close, but you need a pattern rule:

```
$(EXECUTABLE): % : %.c
```

And then a default rule to make it build both:

```
all: $(EXECUTABLE)
```

Comment: Pattern rules likes this are a GNUism it would appear. The built-in single suffix rule for the `.c` suffix does the trick already.

Comment: I'm looking into pattern rules now. Thank you.