# GCC default parameters (-Werror -Wall..)

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

currently I'm using this command to compile my .c files in Mint

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -Wall -Werror filename.c -o filename [-lm]
```

How do I make these parameters default, perhaps include them in the `make filename.c` command? Thanks :)

Comment: A quick option if you didn't want to write a makefile: `alias mygcc='gcc -std=gnu99 -Wall -Werror '`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write makefile like

```
CC = gcc

EXEC = filename

OBJS =  filename.o \

FLAGS = -std=gnu99 -Wall -Werror

LDLIBS = -lm

all: $(EXEC)

$(EXEC): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LDLIBS)

clean:
    -rm -f $(EXEC) *.o
```

Then run make to compile your file

Comment: So create a file containing the above and where should I place it or what's next?

Comment: You need to copy this into file named makefile and put it into your source directory then open terminal change directory to your source code then run make command

Comment: I did it, got this "makefile:7: *** missing separator.  Stop."

Comment: The many spaces should be replaced by *tab* characters. And `FLAGS` should be `CFLAGS`. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16751650/841108)