# "clean" not working in make file

Tags: c++, makefile

This is my make file.

```
 all: observer

    observer: main.o weather_center.o display.o subject.o observer.o
         g++ main.o weather_center.o display.o subject.o observer.o -o observer

    main.o: main.cpp
        g++ -c main.cpp

    weather_center.o: weather_center.cpp
        g++ -c weather_center.cpp

    display.o: display.cpp
        g++ -c display.cpp

    subject.o: subject.cpp
        g++ -c subject.cpp

    observer.o: observer.cpp
        g++ -c observer.cpp

    clean:
        rm -f  *o observer
```

Here I'm trying to use

```
clean:
        rm -f  *o observer
```

To clean up the temporary *.o files. But program compiles and generate the target assembly, but doesn't delete the *.o files. Not showing any errors also.

- I tried `rm -f  *o observer` in terminal. It works fine.
- I have used `Tab` for indent
- there are no files start with `clean` or `rm` in the directory.
- tried `$(RM)` instead of `rm`. but no lucky

Comment: Indentation is crucial in Makefiles. Also, you don't need the `.o` targets, the implicit rules would make them for you.

Comment: @bstamour: no lucky, doesn't work for `rm -f *.o observer`

Comment: Is there a newline missing from the end of the file perhaps? Assuming you've really gotten the indentation right, this should work. In theory, I think you're supposed to include a `.PHONY: clean` line right before your `clean` target, but this shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Have you tried `make clean`? What is the output?

Comment: The indentation is wrong in the sample you posted. Make sure it reflects what you have. If it does, you need to fix the indentation in your Makefile.

Comment: did you eventually try `.PHONY: clean` ? and removing this (accidental?) indentation in all rules except for `all` ?

Comment: You should use more variables in your `Makefile`. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16751650/841108)

Comment: @ Maxim Yegorushkin: This is the result for `make clean`, it gives an error  `make: *** No rule to make target `clean'.  Stop.`

Comment: @ juanchopanza: what is wrong with make file. Please assist me..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the issue. Have to specify `clean` as a target of  `all` otherwise it wont call. generally like this.

`all: [your executive names] clean`

In above case

`all: observer clean`

Here is the full make file of above case

```
all: observer clean

observer: main.o weather_center.o display.o subject.o observer.o
    g++ main.o weather_center.o display.o subject.o observer.o -o observer

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp

weather_center.o: weather_center.cpp
    g++ -c weather_center.cpp

display.o: display.cpp
    g++ -c display.cpp

subject.o: subject.cpp
    g++ -c subject.cpp

observer.o: observer.cpp
    g++ -c observer.cpp

clean:
    rm -f  *o observer
```

Comment: This goes against generally accepted makefile conventions.  This means that invocation of `make` with no explicit target will cause both the `observer` and `clean` targets to be rebuilt, which is probably not what you want.  You would explicitly have to call `make observer` just to build observer without invocation of `clean`

Comment: You should not delete the object files after compilation. If they bother you, compile them in a hidden folder directly.

Comment: To make matters worse, while `observer` and `clean` are both dependencies for `all`, there is no guarantee which order they will be rebuilt in - in fact they could be run concurrently if you use a -j greater than 1.

Comment: @ DigitalTrauma, +1 Thank you for your explanation. Actually what I need to do is when I call `make -f makefileName` final target need to build and remove all the intermediate files. for this how should be the make file and how to run that?

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned, this is likely an indentation issue.  I copied your makefile exactly, touched some dummy .o files and ran it:

```
$ touch main.o weather_center.o display.o subject.o observer.o
$ make clean
Makefile:4: *** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?).  Stop.
$
```

After fixing indentation, it seems to work just fine for me:

```
$ touch main.o weather_center.o display.o subject.o observer.o
$ ls *.o
display.o  main.o  observer.o  subject.o  weather_center.o
$ make clean
rm -f  *o observer
$ ls *.o
ls: cannot access *.o: No such file or directory
$
```

The specific indentation fixes I made were:

- target lines should not have any leading whitespace at all
- recipe lines must start with exactly one tab and no other whitespace

E.g:

```
clean:
    rm -f  *o observer
```

I have saved the fixed version [here](http://pastebin.com/ixqXi0MU), because stackoverflow messes with tabs/whitespace.  Make sure to copy from the **RAW Paste Data**.

---

Having read the question, comments and your self-answer in a little more detail, I think there is possibly some explaining to do about conventional usage of [make](/questions/tagged/make).

You may call the `make` executable with a list of targets to build, or no targets at all.

In the case that targets are specified, then make will attempt to build/rebuild those targets.  For instance, with the corrected Makefile, `make observer` would build the `observer` target (`observer` executable), `make main.o` would simply compile main.cpp to produce main.o, and `make clean` would invoke the `clean` rule to delete the listed files.

On the other hand, if you invoke `make` with no targets, then make will simply use the first target defined in the Makefile as the target that it builds.  The convention is that this target is called `all`, but it can be called whatever you like.  So in the case of the corrected makefile, invoking `make` without explicitly passing any targets should result in `all` and its dependency `observer` being rebuilt.  I suspect this is where the confusion has arisen - invoking `make` for this makefile with no targets explicitly mentioned should ***not*** result in invocation of the `clean` target.  This is the expected `make` behavior.

Comment: Sorry to say, this is not working. same result as my make file. built fine but not cleaning. I'm working in Fedora can it be any issue of Fedora?

Comment: Fedora uses standard Makefile's.  Once the formatting is correct, it will work.

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya Please see my updated answer and comment to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (on Windows), I had my make file as the following:

```
clean:
    rm *.o
```

When opening the terminal, running this command worked fine for me so I thought it was something with my makefile indentation at first.

Well, I realized the default Windows terminal is actually a powershell window that supports `rm *.o`. However, the make clean command was opening up a cmd window that did not support the `rm` command.

My solution ended up turning the `clean:` portion into something that the cmd for Windows supported. Final result ended up being this:

```
clean:
    del *.o
```

Answer (score -1):

all: observer clean #1

```
observer: main.o weather_center.o display.o subject.o observer.o
     g++ main.o weather_center.o display.o subject.o observer.o -o observer

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp

weather_center.o: weather_center.cpp
    g++ -c weather_center.cpp

display.o: display.cpp
    g++ -c display.cpp

subject.o: subject.cpp
    g++ -c subject.cpp

observer.o: observer.cpp
    g++ -c observer.cpp

clean:
    rm -f  *.o #2
```

## 1 fix all: observer to [all: observer clean]

## 2 fix rm -f *o observer to [rm -f *.o]