# How do I change output of C program without editing it?

Tags: c, makefile

I have a C program which I am NOT allowed to edit that looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef YEAR
 #define YEAR "2013"
#endif

int main(){
  printf("Hello world from " YEAR "\n");
  return 0;
}
```

I need to create a makefile to compile this program and change the YEAR to 2014, so that the output will be "Hello world from 2014" without editing the C program. How can I do this?

Comment: It is in the manual -- http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc

Comment: Look at your compiler's `-D` option.

Comment: can the OP please post the University and the class number that this assignment is from?  I am just curious.

Comment: It's from Polotehnica University of Bucharest.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I'm seeing that my question has been answered before. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compilation command should start with `gcc -Wall -DYEAR='"2014"'`. It is up to you to code your `Makefile` with a suitable `CFLAGS` settings. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16751650/841108) should be inspirational.

Answer (score 2):

Just pass a preprocessor directive with the -D parameter, for example:

```
$ cat tmp.c 
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef YEAR
 #define YEAR "2013"
#endif

int main(){
  printf("Hello world from " YEAR "\n");
  return 0;
}

$ gcc -DYEAR=\"1234\" tmp.c -o tmp && ./tmp
Hello world from 1234
```

Comment: It is C code (not C++), so `tmp.c` as a source file (not `tmp.cpp`) and `gcc` as a compiler (not `g++`).

Comment: Basile Starynkevitch, you're right. Updated the answer.