# Signals not defined reference to 'timer_create ' C

Tags: c, gcc, signals

Hello erveryone I get an not defined reference error everytime i complie my code.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <unistd.h>

#define MESSWERTTIMER (SIGRTMAX)
#define MESSREIHENTIMER (SIGRTMAX-1)

static void handler(int signo, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *context){
    if(signo==MESSWERTTIMER){

    }else if(signo==MESSREIHENTIMER){

    }else if(signo ==SIGINT){
        //timer_delete(timerid2);
        //timer_delete(timerid1);
        puts("Messwerte anzeigen");
        perror("CTRL+C cached!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}
//eventuell zwei sigevents zwei timer!!!!!!!

int main(void){
    struct sigaction siga;
    struct sigevent sigev1,sigev2;
    struct itimerspec tspec,tspec2;
    timer_t timerid1,timerid2;
    sigset_t mask;

    memset(&siga,0,sizeof(siga));
    sigemptyset(&siga.sa_mask);
    siga.sa_flags=SA_SIGINFO;
    siga.sa_sigaction = &handler;

    if(sigaction(MESSWERTTIMER,&siga,NULL)==-1){
        perror("sigaction for MESSWERTTIMER failed horribly\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(sigaction(MESSREIHENTIMER,&siga,NULL)==-1){
        perror("sigaction for MESSREIHENTIMER failed horribly\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    sigaction(SIGINT,&siga,NULL);

    //blocking timer signals temporarily
    printf("blocking signals for a short time\n");
    sigemptyset(&mask);
    sigaddset(&mask,MESSWERTTIMER);
    sigaddset(&mask,MESSREIHENTIMER);
    if(sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK,&mask,NULL)==-1){
        perror("sigprocmask\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //creating timers
    sigev1.sigev_notify=SIGEV_SIGNAL;
    sigev1.sigev_signo=MESSWERTTIMER;
    sigev1.sigev_value.sival_ptr= &timerid1;

    sigev2.sigev_notify=SIGEV_SIGNAL;
    sigev2.sigev_signo=MESSREIHENTIMER;
    sigev2.sigev_value.sival_ptr= &timerid2;

    if(timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME,&sigev1,&timerid1)==-1){
        perror("timer create 1\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME,&sigev2,&timerid2)==-1){
        perror("timer create 2\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    tspec.it_value.tv_sec =0 ;
    tspec.it_value.tv_nsec= 100000;
    tspec.it_interval.tv_sec= tspec.it_value.tv_sec;
    tspec.it_interval.tv_nsec= tspec.it_value.tv_nsec;

    tspec2.it_value.tv_sec = 1;
    tspec2.it_value.tv_nsec= 10000;
    tspec2.it_interval.tv_sec= tspec2.it_value.tv_sec;
    tspec2.it_interval.tv_nsec= tspec2.it_value.tv_nsec;

    //unblocking signals
    if(sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK,&mask,NULL)==-1){
        perror("sigprocmask unblock\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(timer_settime(timerid1,0,&tspec,NULL)==-1){
        perror("settime 1\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(timer_settime(timerid2,0,&tspec2,NULL)==-1){
        perror("settime 2\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

}
```

my handler is not done yet, so don`t mind it.

Makefile:

```
nr1:    nr1.c
    gcc -Wall nr1.c -o nr1 

clean:  
    rm -rf nr1
```

And here the compiler message, I hope you don`t mind it is in german:

```
gcc -Wall nr1.c -o nr1 
nr1.c:9:1: warning: "/*" within comment [-Wcomment]
 /****************************************************************************/
 ^
/tmp/ccnoBsjh.o: In Funktion `main':
nr1.c:(.text+0x1f9): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `timer_create'
nr1.c:(.text+0x22d): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `timer_create'
nr1.c:(.text+0x2fc): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `timer_settime'
nr1.c:(.text+0x335): Nicht definierter Verweis auf `timer_settime'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [nr1] Fehler 1
```

I looked through the board and couldn`t find a matching solution. So Iḿ hoping, that you can help me.

Comment: BTW, you could `export LANG=C LC_ALL=C` before posting diagnostics on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile and link as:

```
gcc -Wall nr1.c -o nr1 -lrt
```

Read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) and [timer_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html). See also [timerfd_create(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html) & [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html).

<sup>BTW, typing `man timer_create` would have given you the answer faster than asking here! See [man(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html).</sup>

Regarding your `Makefile`, get some inspiration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16751650/841108).

Comment: Try to find out what RTFM & STFW mean.