# Make: compile object file twice in the same target

Tags: c, makefile

I have the following simple problem in a Makefile:

```
%.o:: %.c
      gcc -o $@ -c $<

lib1.a: test.o
        ar -r $@ test.o
        rm *.o

lib2.a: test.o
        ar -r $@ test.o
        rm *.o

all: lib1.a lib2.a
```

`make lib1.a` or `make lib2.a` work properly. However, `make all` gives:

```
gcc -o test.o -c test.c
ar -r lib1.a test.o
rm *.o
ar -r lib2.a test.o
ar: test.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [lib2.a] Error 1
```

I need to do the `rm *.o` cause I want the object file to compile each time (in my real Makefile, I have a more complex use case where I compile with different flags).

How can I fix this problem? It seems that `make` compiles the object file only once.

I tried with `.PHONY` instead of doing the `rm`, but again, it compiles only once.

Comment: Creating the `.o` file *once* is well in line with how Make works, and shouldn't be a problem (in fact it's a good thing that it *doesn't* repeat that step, time-consumption-wise). What is odd is removing it immediately after running `ar`. Why do you do that?

Comment: try using different names for each object file.

Comment: Better yet, compile each set of .o files into separate directories

Comment: Why do you have `lib1.a` and `lib2.a` containing the *same* object file? You should have a single `libmy.a` ! And you should use more variables in your  `Makefile`, like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16751650/841108)

Comment: This is a simplified version of my actual Makefile. What I try to do is to create different libraries with one common object file and some others that are different. However, for some of the libraries I compile the common object file with different flags. I guess I could indeed try to create different object files as @iharob suggested.

Comment: @VasileiosTrigonakis As a rule of thumb, if you want to compile with different flags in *the same run* the results should go into different files. I'm still curious about the `rm`s, though...

Comment: @Biffen Are you curious why it does not work, or why do I use them? If it's the latter, there isn't any particular reason apart from cleaning up and achieving the recompilation of the object files (with possibly different flags).

Comment: add another target that performs the two 'ar' statements then performs the 'rm' statement.  the 'all' target then has a dependency of this new target.   BTW: the 'all' target should be first so that it is executed when the user only enters 'make' with no parameter

Comment: @VasileiosTrigonakis The common way to do it is to have a separate `clean` target that does all forms of clean-up, and is used explicitly. That way you won't necessarily have to redo every step on each invocation. Do with that information what you like, it's just convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your makefile is a bit against the `make` logic, this is why the result is not what you expect:

- Here you define two targets (`lib1.a` and `lib2.a`) with a common dependency: `test.o`.
- Then you define the rule `all` (which, by the way, should be `.PHONY` but this isn't a problem here) that depends on `lib1.a` and `lib2.a`.

So, in order to "do" `all`, `make` have to build `lib1.a` and `lib2.a`. They both depend on `test.o`, so `make` builds `test.o` once, then build `lib1.a` and `lib2.a`, expecting that the recipes you defined will just build those files, and nothing more.

The problem is that you delete `test.o` *in the recipe for `lib1.a` and `lib2.a`*, although this action is not needed to build them, this is something you want to do when cleaning, not building.

There are two solutions:

1. Move the deletion operation in a rule that is meant to do that (a `.PHONY` rule named `clean` for example).
2. The use of [intermediate targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html) which will be deleted when they're not needed anymore. In fact, you can achieve that without even thinking about intermediate targets if you simply delete the first rule of your makefile (the `%.o:: %.c` one), [because `make` already has an implicit rule that does that](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) using intermediate targets.

Answer (score 0):

Make is a rule-based system. Rules are declarative: you declare what you want built from what, you don't specify the order in which this happens (unless you can't avoid it).  So a good Makefile is declarative: all results are *declared* like in a declarative programming language. They are like `final` variables in Java: you bind them to a value, you don't reassign them to a different value afterwards.

Make is also file-based: its "variables", targets and prerequisites are files.

So if you want to build two different things, don't call them by the same name!  If you want two different `test.o` files, call them differently. The problem will go away without you needing to try and convince `make` that it should be like an imperative programming language, which it was specifically designed not to be. If you want an imperative build specification, use a shell script.