# Make file executables

Tags: c, makefile

I'm trying to define specific lines of code to be run using a makefile like so

```
all: my_prog

my_prog: main.o count.o median.o maximum.o 
    gcc main.o count.o median.o maximum.i -o my_prog
main.o: main.c count.h median.h maximum.h
    gcc count.c -c
median: median.c median.h
    gcc -g -DMEDIAN median.c count.o main.o -o median
maximum: maximum.c maximum.h
    gcc -g -DMAXIMUM maximum.c count.o main.o -o maximum
clean:
    rm -f *.o my_prog median maximum
```

I'm trying to make the median and maximum files in my main function dependent on whether the user wants to use them or not and in my main.c the functions are defined

```
#ifdef MAXIMUM
long max = maximum(arr, size);

printf("The maximum is %Ld. \n", max);
#endif


#ifdef MEDIAN
long med = median(arr, size);

printf("The median is %Ld. \n", med);
#endif
```

The rest of my code works fine but when I try to run the executables it acts like these lines of code aren't even here.

Comment: I assume you use GNU  `make`. Then please use known make variables like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16751650/841108)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining the macros only on link steps is not enough. They are preprocessor directives. So you should define them in *compile* step.

You may use `gcc -DMEDIAN -o filename_median.o -c filename.c` to generate an object file dedicated for `median` and another one for `maximum`.

So in your case the Makefile would look like:

```
all: my_prog median maximum

my_prog: main.o count.o median.o maximum.o 
    gcc main.o count.o median.o maximum.i -o my_prog
main.o: main.c count.h median.h maximum.h
    gcc -o main.o main.c -c
main_median.o: main.c count.h median.h maximum.h
    gcc -DMEDIAN -o main_median.o main.c -c
main_maximum.o: main.c count.h median.h maximum.h
    gcc -DMAXIMUM -o main_maximum.o main.c -c
median: median.c median.h main_median.o
    gcc -g -DMEDIAN median.c count.o main_median.o -o median
maximum: maximum.c maximum.h main_maximum.o
    gcc -g -DMAXIMUM maximum.c count.o main_maximum.o -o maximum
clean:
    rm -f *.o my_prog median maximum
```

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't seem to understand, I'm sorry to ask this but can you walk me through step by step?

Comment: Should use `CC` & `CFLAGS` like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16751650/841108)

Comment: Thanks so much for walking me through it timrau! It worked like a charm and I think I understand makefiles much better now!