# makefile - how to exclude file extension suffix from a variable

Tags: c, makefile

the next makefile receive the file to compile from its command line arg -ARGS. For example

make ARGS="out.c"

I would like to replace the name of the created executable "run" with the variable ARGS excluding the suffix

in this example : run="out"

```css
all: Task1
Task1: outputs/output.o
 gcc -g -m32 -Wall -o run outputs/output.o 

outputs/output.o: outputs/${ARGS}
 gcc -m32 -g -w -Wall -ansi -c -o outputs/output.o outputs/${ARGS} 


.PHONY: clean
run: clean Task1
clean:
 rm -f outputs\output.o Task1
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. How exactly do you invoke `make`, and what do you want it to do?

Comment: Are you sure you want the object file to be named `output.o`?

Comment: On which OS? If on Linux, the backslash for the `clean` target `rm` command is wrong!

Comment: Why does the `clean` rule attempt to remove `Task1`, a file that nothing ever builds?

Comment: I'm really surprised people spend more time asking ill-formulated questions (and waiting for answers) here than reading documentation.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: 1) Don't forget about selection bias, and 2) don't underestimate human laziness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crude way to do what you ask is simply:

```
EXEC := $(basename $(ARGS))
all: Task1
Task1: outputs/output.o
    gcc -g -m32 -Wall -o $(EXEC) outputs/output.o
```

A better way is:

```
EXEC := $(basename $(ARGS))
all: $(EXEC)
$(EXEC): outputs/output.o
    gcc -g -m32 -Wall -o $(EXEC) outputs/output.o
```

Better still:

```
EXEC := $(basename $(ARGS))
all: $(EXEC)
$(EXEC): outputs/output.o
    gcc -g -m32 -Wall -o $@ $^
```

Answer (score 1):

If using [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/) you need the [basename](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#File-Name-Functions) function, perhaps as `$(basename $(AUX))`. Maybe variables like `$(*F)` might be useful too (please read the documentation). However, your `Makefile` is probably wrong.

<sup>I can't suggest an improvement, because what you want to do and to happen is unclear.</sup>

BTW, use [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) (as `remake -x`) or at least `make --trace`  (with a recent enough GNU make 4.x) to understand what `make` is doing and why.

Also, you'll find several examples of `Makefile`-s: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14180540/841108) & [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16751650/841108)
etc... Don't forget that `make` has a many builtin rules, you'll get them by running `make -p`

<sup>You won't lose your time by reading the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) of GNU make, and some tutorials, and some examples of `Makefile`-s.</sup>

Comment: hi thanks for your help. I suppose to create a makefile for compiling c with 2 requirements : 1. The makefile recieves its filename from the command line  2. The executable file created by the makefile should be with the same name without the suffix . I am open for any improvements .However, I havent seen  a better way to create makefile for my requirements

Comment: My suggestion is to spend an hour reading the documentation and the examples. It is faster, and you'll learn more, than just waiting for answers on a forum.