# Including headers file using GCC

Tags: c, gcc

Sorry. I think this question would be very easy to you guys.

I have two c files and one h file, I put those two `.c` files `stack.c` and `main.c` and one `.h` file `stack.h` inside a folder named `"test"` at `Desktop`.

So they are in `C:\Users\user\Desktop\test`

However when i try to test this code by writing

```
gcc -c stack.c sq_main.c -l stack.h
```

It continuously shows `"unkown type name ..."`

I think the header file is not included into those two `.c` files.

Actually I wrote the code

```c
#include "stack.h"
```

Inside `stack.c` and `main.c`

Can anyone tell me how to include header file properly?

Comment: shouldn't it be `#include "stack.h"`?

Comment: If you could provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the very first error or warning message produced by the compiler then it would be obvious what is wrong.  Right now you are just expecting us to read your mind.

Comment: The syntax for includes is `#include "file" or <lib>` you had `include "stack.h"`. I was wondering if that was a type-o on the question or an error in your code.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Sorry. to add some more information, i did some googling and found out that if those .c files cannot recognize the header file, then the cmd window will keep showing "stack.h error: unkown type name 'functino name'"
sorry i was just a visual studio user and trying to do programming using gcc...

Comment: @Nindaff: "*`... or <lib>`*" No, `#include`s never include libs, but always and ever files, at least if used correctly.

Comment: @alk Yes that's a good point, I was trying to point out the difference in syntax for including a system headers.

Comment: @Nindaff thank you. i will re go through my code :D

Comment: Please show full error output and some erroneous lines from stack.h

Comment: Did you consider installing Linux on your laptop. It might be simpler to use GCC on Linux (since it is its main native computer) than on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) wrongly. I guess you are on Linux (or on something emulating it like [MinGW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) ...)

If you insist on giving several commands in a terminal, you'll need to run

```
 gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -c stack.c
 gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -c sq_main.c
```

these two commands are building object files `stack.o` & `sq_main.o` (from `stack.c` & the `#include`-d `stack.h`, and `sq_main.c` & the `#include`-d `stack.h`, respectively). The options `-Wall -Wextra` are asking for all warnings and some extra warnings. The `-g` option asks for debugging information. The `-c` option asks for compiling only. Assuming that they are enough for your program, you need to [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29) these object files to make an executable:

```
 gcc -g stack.o sq_main.o -o myprogram
```

You might need to add `-I`*include-directory* options to the compiling commands (the first two), and you might need to add `-L`*library-directory* and `-l`*library-name* to the linking command. Order of arguments to `gcc` matters a lot. You could also add `-H` to ask the compiler to show which files are included. And [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) has a lot of other options. Read the [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) chapter of its documentation.

<sup>The `.o` suffix might be `.obj` on most Windows systems. You might also need `myprogram.exe` instead of `myprogram`. I never used Windows so I cannot help more.</sup>

In practice, you should use [GNU `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make) and write some `Makefile`; [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16751650/841108) answer might inspire you.