# gdb error: not in executable format: file not recognized

Tags: c, linux, gdb

I am trying to debug my project, which consists of 5 files. I built the project using a Makefiles-system. My Makefile looks as the following:

```
CC=gcc

CFLAGS= -g -c

all: main.o io_ops.o rw_ops.o help_functions.o
    $(CC) -o db main.o io_ops.o rw_ops.o help_functions.o
io_ops.o:io_ops.c  db_ops.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS)  io_ops.c db_ops.h
rw_ops.o: rw_ops_c db_ops.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) rw_ops.c db_ops.h 
help_functions.o: help_functions.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) help_functions.c
clean:
    rm *.o db
```

My executable file is named db. So I run on my terminal the following command:

```
gdb db
```

Then I type the following command on gdb:

```
list main.c
```

I get the **following error: main.c not defined**
I try to type the following command:

```
list main.c
```

I get the following error:
main.c: not in **executable format:file not recognized**

To ensure that my gdb is 64-bit-program, I typed the following command:

```
(gdb) show configuration
 This GDB was configured as follows:
configure --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
         --with-auto-load-dir=$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load
         --with-auto-load-safe-path=$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load
         --with-expat
         --with-gdb-datadir=/usr/share/gdb (relocatable)
         --with-jit-reader-dir=/usr/lib/gdb (relocatable)
         --without-libunwind-ia64
         --with-lzma
         --with-python=/usr (relocatable)
         --with-separate-debug-dir=/usr/lib/debug (relocatable)
         --with-system-gdbinit=/etc/gdb/gdbinit
         --with-zlib
         --without-babeltrace
```

And this is some informations about my executable:

> db: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=25731950b7f76cf428eeca5fcc534555d677f3dc, not stripped

I do not know, what is the problem. Any idea?

Comment: Your `Makefile` is grossly wrong; see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16751650/841108)

Comment: why is my Makefile wrong?

Comment: In particular, because you compile explicitly header files. And you should use `-Wall -g` as your compilation flags.

Comment: -Wall: Why should I use it. What does it do?

Comment: @amitakCs `-Wall` activates "all" warnings (well, not all, but many of them, the most important, the one that almost 100% sure shows a programming mistake). You want `-Wall` . Always. Do use it. `-Wall`  is your friend. `-Wall` will save you a considerable time in debugging.

Comment: thank you for the explanation::)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is `list main.c:1`

`list` is not made to list a file the way you use it. From gdb help:

> (gdb) help list
>
> List specified function or line.
>
> With no argument, lists ten more lines after or around previous
>   listing.
>
> "list -" lists the ten lines before a previous ten-line listing.
>
> One argument specifies a line, and ten lines are listed around that
>   line. Two arguments with comma between specify starting and ending
>   lines to list. Lines can be specified in these ways:
>
> LINENUM, to list around that line in current file,
>
> FILE:LINENUM, to list around that line in that file,
>
> FUNCTION, to list around beginning of that function,
>
> FILE:FUNCTION, to distinguish among like-named static functions.
>
> *ADDRESS, to list around the line containing that address.
>
> With two args if one is empty it stands for ten lines away from the
>   other arg.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not know, what is the problem.

You likely want `list main` instead.

Explanation: there are [four forms](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/List.html#List) of `list` command, none take filename as an argument.

Comment: Well, on my gdb 7.10, there are 2: `FILE:LINENUM, to list around that line in that file` and `FILE:FUNCTION, to distinguish among like-named static functions`. The doc does not seem up to date.