# How to link my C program to a static/dynamic library?

Tags: c, makefile, shared-libraries

I'm trying to link my C program to both a static and dynamic library to see the difference. How do I do that?
I've made my own Makefile:

```
# ------ executable rule  -----------
app : app.o
        -gcc -g  app.o -o app

# ------ intermeditate object files rule (.o) -------
app.o : main.c
         -gcc -g -c main.c -o app.o
```

I've only shown you some of my Makefile as I think the rest is unnecessary.
I've tried to write `-L. lstatic` after `-gcc -g  app.o -o app` but it didn't work.

Comment: Either use `-static` or explicitly pass in the file you want to link against just like you would a ".o" file.   [Also, read the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html)

Comment: And if I want to link it to a dynamic library then I've to write `-gcc -g  app.o -o app -rdynamic` ?

Comment: No. Dynamic linking is the default. So leave out `-static` will do. When linking without `-static` the linker (at least gnu) will first look for the dynamic library and if it doesn't find that it will then look for the static library.

Comment: As far as "seeing the difference":  Under most Linux distros, you can use `ldd`, `readelf -d`, or `file` on your resulting binary to tell you if its dynamically or statically linked.

Answer (score 0):

Read about [invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html). Order of arguments to `gcc` matters a lot!

You could use `-static` or `-Bstatic`

You can also *explicitly* link with *static* libraries, by giving some `/usr/lib/libfoo.a` (or some appropriate file path) argument at link time.

You'll better improve your `Makefile` to use existing builtin rules (try `make -p`) and conventional variables, e.g. like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16751650/841108). Read the [documentation of GNU `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html).