# How can I give permissions in a basic makefile

Tags: linux, makefile

How do I add permissions to this simple make file?

```
all: shell ls cat groups

shell: shell.o cd.o
    gcc shell.o cd.o -o shell

cat: cat.o 
    gcc -c cat.c -o cat

ls: ls.o header.h
    gcc -c ls.c -o ls

groups: groups.o groups.h 
    gcc -c groups.c -o groups

shell.o: shell.c tlpi_hdr.h
    gcc -c shell.c

cd.o: cd.c tlpi_hdr.h
    gcc -c cd.c

cat.o: cat.c tlpi_hdr.h
    gcc -c cat.c 

ls.o: ls.c header.h
    gcc -c ls.c

groups.o: groups.c groups.h
    gcc -c groups.c 

clean: 
    rm *.o shell cat ls groups
```

I need to run cat/ls/groups/cd within the shell that I created, but can't because it doesn't have permissions. How can I do this?

Comment: The compiler normally makes the programs it produces executable so you don't need to. You may need to add the directory to your `PATH` though. How is your `cd` going to work as a separate binary for?

Comment: Learn more about `make` and its builtin rules. Try `make -p`. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16751650/841108)

Comment: Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/). Notice that `cd` cannot be an external program (it has to be a shell builtin).

Answer (score 1):

As an example, this rule:

```
groups: groups.o groups.h 
    gcc -c groups.c -o groups
```

tells GCC to produce an object file called `groups` (instead of the normal `groups.o`) because you included the `-c` option.  Object files are not executables, so the compiler doesn't make them executable, hence your problem with the permissions.  Note that the rule requires `make` to build `groups.o`, but then proceeds to ignore the object file because it recompiles the source code.

You wanted to write something more like:

```
groups: groups.o 
    gcc groups.o -o groups
groups.o: groups.h
```

You need to use a lot more macros — or you could leave the rules out of the makefile since `make` knows how to build `groups` from `groups.c`.

You should also be compiling with warning options.  At minimum `-Wall`; preferably `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` (and I use still more options than these).  You might want optimization (`-O3`); you might want debugging (`-g`).  These are normally handled via setting macros and then using them in the commands.