# Makefile error in C linux

Tags: linux, makefile

I have an error while making my makefile in linux. Here's my code:

```make
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -m32 -g -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -O0
SHELL_SOURCES = Shell.c

SHELL = Shell

.PHONY: all target1 clean

all: target1 

target1: $(SHELL)

$(SHELL): $(SHELL_SOURCES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

clean:
rm -rf $(SHELL)
```

The error I get is:

```
gcc -Wall -m32 -g -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -O0 Shell.c -o Shell
make: Shell: Command not found
Makefile:16: recipe for target 'Shell' failed
make: *** [Shell] Error 127
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `SHELL` as a variable in a Makefile, it is used to know what shell (/bin/sh, /bin/bash, etc) will be used in your Makefile.

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -m32 -g -fno-stack-protector -z execstack -O0
EXE_SOURCES = Shell.c

EXE = Shell


.PHONY: all target1 clean

all: target1 

target1: $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(EXE_SOURCES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf $(EXE)
```

Comment: More precisely, `$(SHELL)` is used to run *every* action line in rules, and since `Shell` does not exist when running the first action, `make` is complaining.

Answer (score 2):

Take more time to read [documentation of GNU `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html)

You should remove spaces around variable assignments,  e.g. code

```
 CC= gcc
```

Beware that <kbd>tab</kbd> characters are significant in `Makefile`-s (in [rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rule-Example.html#Rule-Example), for their action lines). Use some editor aware of that (e.g. `emacs` has a mode for [`Makefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile)). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16751650/841108) example (but the rule action should really start with a <kbd>tab</kbd> character). Notably, you need a <kbd>tab</kbd> just before the `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@` and another one before `rm`.

Consider also using [`remake`](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) `-x` to debug your `Makefile`, or at least `make --trace`

But the main bug was indeed, as [answered by Cpatricio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41346374/841108), to use the [`SHELL` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html). Be careful when using [variables or names already known](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Name-Index.html) to `make`. Actually, I have the habit of prefixing my `make` variable names with a common prefix, so you could have defined your variables like `JOJOIGA_SOURCES=$(wildcard *.c)`, `JOJOIGA_SHELL=Shell` etc....

Comment: Yeah, My original code has tabs.. had some trouble copying the code exactly as it is. Thanks anyway :)