# Linking .c and .h files

Tags: c

For my program I am linking 3 files in total. A main.c, sortfile.c and my.h(header file). For my sortfile.c I am implementing a OddEven Sort. I am unsure whether my coding algorithm is correct. Also would like to know what information usually goes in a header file. Is it only the other two c files vide #include?

```
#include <stdio.h>


void swap(int *, int *);
void Odd_Even_Sort(int *);


/* swaps the elements */
void swap(int * x, int * y)
{
    int temp;

    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}

/* sorts the array using oddeven algorithm */
void Odd_Even_Sort(int * x)
{
    int sort = 0, i;

    while (!sort)
    {
        sort = 1;
        for (i = 1;i < MAX;i += 2)
        {
            if (x[i] > x[i+1])
            {
                swap(&x[i], &x[i+1]);
                sort = 0;
            }
        }
        for (i = 0;i < MAX - 1;i += 2)
        {
            if (x[i] > x[i + 1])
            {
                swap(&x[i], &x[i + 1]);
                sort = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

I did not include a main in the sortfile.c because I intended to put main in the main.c file.

Comment: What do you need help with? Do you get compilation errors?

Comment: @giusti As to how I would link this to my main.c, haven't compiled this code as of yet

Comment: Your original question is unclear. This is a Q&A site. Rewrite the question to make it specific and answerable.

Comment: Write a *Makefile* and run `make`. You may, of course, compile each `*.c` module separately, like `gcc -O2 -Wall -o x.o x.c` and then link result `gcc -o prog x.o y.o`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You look confused. Read first the wikipage on [linkers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29) and on [compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler). You don't link [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code) files, but only [object files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) and [libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29).

<sup>(I am guessing and supposing and hoping for you that you are using Linux)</sup>

You also compile [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29) into object files.

[Header files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_directive) are for the [preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) (the first "phase" of the compilation). The [preprocessing](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) is a textual operation. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8110940/841108) for some hint.

So you probably want to compile your `main.c` into `main.o` with

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -c main.c -o main.o
```

(the `-Wall` asks for all warnings, so never forget that; the `-Wextra` asks for more of them; the `-g` asks for debugging information; `-c` asks to compile some source into some object file; order of [program arguments](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html#Option-Summary) to `gcc` matters a big lot).

Likewise, you want to compile your `sortfile.c` into `sortfile.o`. I leave as an exercise to get the right command doing that.

Finally, you want to get an executable program `myprogsort`, by linking both object files. Do that with

```
gcc -g main.o sortfile.o -o myprogsort
```

But you really want to use some [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool. Learn about [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/). Write your [`Makefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile) (beware, <kbd>tab</kbd>s are important in it). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16751650/841108) example. Don't forget to try `make -p`  to understand (and take advantage of) all the builtin rules `make` is knowing.

Learn to use some [version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) software, e.g. [git](https://git-scm.com/), for your source code and tests.

Consider also using code generators (like [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) for [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) tasks) if and when relevant. Repetitive code could be generated by preprocessors (e.g. [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp)).

> Also would like to know what information usually goes in a header file.

*Conventionally* you want only *declarations* in your common header file (which you would `#include` in every source file composing a translation unit). You can also add *definitions* of `static inline` functions. Read more about [inline functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function) (you probably don't need them at first).

Don't forget to learn how to use the [`gdb` debugger](https://www.sourceware.org/gdb/). You probably will run

```
gdb ./myprogsort
```

more than once. Don't forget to rebuild your thing after changes to source code.

Once you are confident with your code and have debugged simple bugs, you would compile it with optimization flags like  `-O2` (in addition, or in place of `-g`). This is needed to benchmark your executable. Learn about [profiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)).

Some programs are designed to accept plugins (extending their features). On Linux or POSIX systems, this uses [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and [dlsym(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html). Other programs cooperate with other executables and communicate with them (e.g. carefully using [popen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html), [sockets](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html), RPC/XDR, JSONRPC, etc....)

Look also inside the source code of some medium sized [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) project coded in C on [github](http://github.com/). You'll learn a big lot.

NB. On serious software projects senior developers would decide on some coding guidelines (e.g. [GNU standards](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/index.html)), rules and conventions, and others would review the code, perhaps even developing some [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) to validate *some* of these coding rules. Be however aware of [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem).

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, also I was instructed to display the amount of numbers in the file at index [0] for the array(a[ ]) then the preceding numbers. For example, lets say there are 5 numbers in the file. In the array it should be `a[0]5 a[1]1 a[2]2 a[3]3 a[4]4 a[5]5`. Any idea on how to code that?

Comment: No, I won't do your homework. As I suggested, study the source code of some medium sized free software project. *Read* some *existing* code before writing your own. And please consider that you'll learn a lot more by doing *yourself* a homework, than by asking others to do it. You need to learn (not to have your homework done by others).