# Does make behave different in different linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, makefile, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-16.04

I have a make file that works just fine on this version of Linux. HOWEVER
why doesn't it run on this other version...

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
codename :      trusty
```

right here... it doesn't run on this one? why?

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

I get this error on xenial...why?

```
Ubuntu mate $:make
gcc: error: missing filename after ‘-o’
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Here is my make file ( updated, last post did not have this )

```
CFLAGS = gcc -g
OBJ = dummyDriverX1.o x1.o error.o

# Automatic substitution using suffix rules to
%.o: %.c
    ${CFLAGS} -c $< 

%.o: %.cpp
    ${CFLAGS} -c $<

# Building x1 based on the required .o files
pell: ${OBJ}
    ${CFLAGS} -o pell ${OBJ}

clean:
    rm ${OBJ}
```

Comment: Show the makefile.

Comment: The version of Linux is not relevant, what matters is the version of `make`.

Comment: the makefile might depend on other scripts that has issues.

Comment: Not sure if this has any value but when I call for
make -v ( so that I may see the version, as according to the man pages)
I get a gcc: fatal error: no input files compliation terminated.

Comment: Are you sure that this is the complete and unchanged makefile on both machines? It looks like in one version `$(OBJ)` is never assigned a value and therefore make tries to compile in the recipe of `pell` instead of linking. Moreover the output can't be from exactly this rule, as I see no `gcc -g ...` after starting make.

Comment: Yup, this is what it looks like. OBJ is assigned at the top. Starting to think that maybe I should uninstall make then reinstall it.

Comment: Your `Makefile` is really wrong. See  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16751650/841108)  example; remove your `Makefile`, run `make -p` to understand the builtin rules, and write your new `Makefile` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your Makefile replaces make's good built-in default rules with inferior homegrown cargo cult guesswork. Make knows exactly how to compile a C file with the correct flags and options for your compiler; don't try to outsmart it, especially if you aren't familiar with the compiler. (So, not properly a make problem per se; but letting make use its default will fix your incorrect compiler invocation.)