# How to make a basic C makefile?

Tags: gcc, makefile

I am trying to make a simple Makefile for a hello world program in c
currently, I compile with:

```
gcc -Wall -std=c99 helloWorld.c
```

In the Makefile what I have so far is:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -std=c99

helloWorld.exe: helloWorld.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o helloWorld.exe
```

Also, that is a tab and not spaces in the second line
When I enter either make or make --trace I get:

make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Comment: There are some issues with your Makefile, but they are addressed in the answers below.  I just wanted to make sure you know: the whitespace in front of `$(CC)` is a <tab> character.  It's an easy thing to miss if you're new to `make`...and some editors silently replace tabs with spaces.

Comment: Edit your question to show the output of `make --trace` and/or `make`

Comment: What is the actual name of your make file? Are you in that directory when you run make?

Comment: Name of the make file is Makefile, it is in the same directory as the c file that I am compiling and yes I am also in that directory

Comment: On what operating system are you doing this? I hope you use Linux or some POSIX system

Comment: I'm on Windows but I use cygwin for the terminal

Answer (score 2):

Read [documentation of `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html). Beware that <kbd>TAB</kbd> characters are *significant* in [`Makefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile)-s (most other [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) systems, e.g. [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/), don't have this historical misfeature). Your question and my answer don't show these tabs but you need to be sure they are there (each code line starting here with *several* spaces should really start with a single tab character).

> ```
> helloWorld.exe: helloWorld.c
>     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o helloWorld.exe
> ```

is **wrong**. You don't pass `helloWorld.c` to `gcc`.

You want at least

```
 helloWorld.exe: helloWorld.c
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o helloWorld.exe helloWorld.c
```

and you could (and actually should) use the `$@` and `$^`  special make [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#). Be also aware of builtin rules (try `make -p`).
Perhaps on your system having just `helloWorld.exe: helloWorld.c` without explicit actions might be enough. I recommend having the usual `clean:` target with the appropriate rule.

You probably want to explicitly set in your `Makefile`, if [invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html):

```
CFLAGS= -Wall -g
```

because you should ask for all warnings and debug info (since `gcc` won't produce them if not asked to).

To debug your `Makefile`: try first `make -n`. Then `make --trace` and perhaps use [`remake`](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) with `-x`.

You'll find many examples of `Makefile`, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16751650/841108).

Be sure to clean your file tree (either with a good - but still missing - `clean` target and then `make clean`, or manually by removing any object files and any executable) after each edition of `Makefile`.

> When I enter either `make` or `make --trace` I get:
>   `make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.`

This means that you are running that `make` command in the wrong directory. Before running `make` check with `pwd` or `/bin/pwd` your [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory). It probably is not what you believe it is. List also files in it (with `ls` on Linux and POSIX, with `DIR` on MSDOS & Windows); you should see both your `Makefile` and your `helloWorld.c` at least.

Check also that your [`PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) is correct (e.g. with `echo $PATH` on POSIX systems).

PS. I am surprised of the `.exe` suffix. On my Linux system I don't use and don't need it.

Comment: So I added helloWorld.c after the helloWorld.exe on the second line but it still does not work. I'm on windows using cygwin if that makes any difference.

Comment: Then edit your question to show output of `make --trace`  at least, and check that your `Makefile` does contain  the tab character appropriately.