# gmp strange behaviour that doesn't let me compile new project

Tags: c, compiler-errors, gmp

I've installed on my ubuntu gmp using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev
```

and it worked fine.
Now I'm trying to create a new project put simply writing

```
  #include "gmp.h"
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <time.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <unistd.h>




  int main(){

    mpz_t num;
    mpz_init(num);
    printf("%s\n",mpz_get_str (NULL, 10, num));

    mpz_clear(num);


   return 0;

  }
```

give me

```
> gcc -lgmp mil.c  /tmp/ccHvV9kT.o: In function `main':
> mil.c:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `__gmpz_init'
> mil.c:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to `__gmpz_get_str'
> mil.c:(.text+0x49): undefined reference to `__gmpz_clear' collect2:
> error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I just copy-pasted the code of my previous project and I get the same error(in all the function that I created), but compiling my old project I don't get any error.
What is my problem???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Order of arguments to `gcc` matters](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) a big lot.

Try to use (you want warnings and debug info, so)

```
 gcc -Wall -Wextra -g mil.c -lgmp -o milprog
```

Then run `./milprog`. You may want to [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) on it, with

```
gdb ./milprog
```

and you may want (for benchmarking purposes) to ask the compiler to optimize, by adding (before `-g`) something like `-O2 -march=native`

Learn to [use GNU `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) (or some other [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool, like [`ninja`](http://ninja-build.org/)), see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16751650/841108).

Be sure to use a version control system like [git](http://git-scm.com/).

BTW, I find more logical and more elegant to include `"gmp.h"` *after* (not before, as you did) the inclusion of standard headers (like `<stdio.h>`).

Comment: I am not sure it is that helpful to mix general advice (-O, debugger, make, git) with the specific answer to this question.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful