# How can i create makefile for gcc on a server-client program?

Tags: c, linux, makefile

There are 3 files : "client.c" , "server.c" and "util.h"

I need to compile this with gcc on linux and have 2 executables, 1 for client and another for server .
But it can be possible to have more than 1 client running and ONLY 1 server.
Im not sure how to do this , create 1 makefile only for client and another for server or just 1 and it can work ?

Comment: Create multiple targets `client: client.c util.h`, `server: server.c util.h`, and then `all: client server`. It would also help if you rewrite your question, because it is not really comprehensible right now.

Comment: You create a `Makefile` with a [source code editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor) understanding tabs. I prefer [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/). Your question is off-topic on SO. You run your programs in a terminal (or thru the `gdb` debugger) and you might open several terminal windows. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16751650/841108) of `Makefile`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is only one Makefile to create:

```
TARGET=client server 
normal: $(TARGET)
client: client.c
    gcc -Wall client.c -o client
server: server.c
    gcc -Wall server.c -o server
clean:
    $(RM) $(TARGET)
```

It will create 2 executables (server and client) to run. Execute the server once simultanously with one/multiple client(s).

[Edit]
I was advised an improved solution:

```
TARGET=client server 
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -Wall -Wextra -g
normal: $(TARGET)
client: client.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) client.c -o client
server: server.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) server.c -o server
clean:
    $(RM) $(TARGET)
```

Comment: I recommend `CC=gcc` and `CFLAGS= -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: Could also add in the dependencies on util.h for the object files too.

Comment: Just 1 question: If i need to compile the program with another flags like "-pthread" , should i add it after the  $(CC) $(CFFLAGS) ... client -pthread ?Thank you in advance

Comment: In orther to do so, add it to the 3rd  line like this
CFLAGS= -pthread -Wall -Wextra -g